# Create a TABLE in MySQL query in JSON format with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

is there any possibility to create a new Table with JSON Format to MySQL.
I have the following test JSON file and want to create a new table out of it

```
[
    {
        "name": "arbeitszeitmodelle",
        "columns": {
            "test": "SMALLINT",
            "test2": "STRING"
        }
    }
]
```

In the following line is the code I want to create the table. Is it there possible to create the columns with JSON

```
con.query("CREATE TABLE " + element.name + " /*What is to fill here?*/")
```

I thank you all :D

Comment: you have to parse your object litteral to build the right SQL syntax. What have you tried so far ? It won't be possible to do that in a single line of code however

Comment: do you have a primary key with autoincrement? waht about the char length for string?

Comment: @Pierre I thought that there's an easy way to set the columns by JSON. So I have to convert it to the right format of mysql query out of the JSON file?

Comment: @NinaScholz No I forgot to implement it. But thank you for that hint :)

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to use an ORM to do all your database queries and CRUD operations rather than building your own raw query.

For Node.JS one of the most popular ORM's is [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize).

You can read the documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#new-databases-versus-existing-databases) for more details.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes. This helps me. Thank you for that :D

Comment: Sure! Do leave me an up vote for the answer! Thanks!